# Exact sequence of groups: proof of injectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence

There must be a duplicate being the question very introductory, but I was not able to find it.

We have the following diagram

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 
1&\to& H &\to & G &\overset{\pi}{\to} & G/H &\to & 1\\
&& \downarrow  & & \downarrow f && \downarrow g & & \\
1&\to& H' &\to & G'& \overset{\pi'}{\to} & G'/H' &\to & 1\\
\end{array}$$

Suppose that

1. $f$ is homomorphism
2. $H'\triangleleft G'$
3. $H=f^{-1}(H')$
4. $H\triangleleft G$
5. $f$ is surjective

> Prove that $g$ is an isomorphism.

Since $g\circ\pi=\pi'\circ f$ and $\pi,\pi',f$ are surjective, then $g$ is surjective.

The problem is with injectivity. (A) From $g(aH)=g(bH)$ I should derive $aH=bH$. Or (B) prove that $\operatorname{ker} g=\{H\}$.

(A) Working backwards I get 
$$
aH=bH
\iff
a^{-1}b\in H
\iff
f(a^{-1}b)\in H'\\
\iff
(f(a))^{-1}f(b)\in H'
\iff
f(a)H'=f(b)H'
$$

Now, if $g(aH)=g(bH)$ how do I get $f(a)H'=f(b)H'$?

Method (B) would probably be nicer, but no idea how to start.

Comment: are the rows exact?

Comment: Note that $g(aH)=g(bH)$ implies $f(a)H'=f(b)H'$ by commutativity of right-handed square, since $f(a)H'=(\pi'\circ f)(a)=(g\circ\pi)(a)=g(aH)$ and, similarly, $f(b)H'=g(bH)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove directly that $\DeclareMathOperator\Ker{Ker}\Ker g$ is trivial, note that
\begin{align}
\pi^{-1}\Ker g
&=\Ker(g\circ\pi)\\
&=\Ker(\pi'\circ f)\\
&=f^{-1}\Ker\pi'\\
&=f^{-1}H'\\
&=H
\end{align}
Since $\pi$ is surjective, we get
$\Ker g=\pi[\pi^{-1}\Ker g]=\pi[H]=\{1\}$.